# Can I cast to VLA?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, variable-length-array

I know that variable array length is a compiler's extension, but am I allowed to cast to VLA?

Next example compiles fine with next command:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra cast.cpp  -ansi
```

Code follows:

```
#include <iostream>


struct A
{
    int p;
    char l;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    (void)argv;

    const int length = argc;

    void* msg = new int[ length ];

    A (&arr)[ length ] = reinterpret_cast< A (&)[ length ] >( msg );


    std::cout << arr[3].p << std::endl;
}
```

---

I am mostly interested about c++03, but also for newer c++ standard.

---

Gcc version:

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Comment: @Rakete1111 Reference to VLA. Feel free to edit the question, if I didn't formulate something correctly

Comment: Let's start with: C++ doesn't have VLAs *at all* - so if you're interested what the standard has to say about VLAs, then the answer obviously is "nothing". A corresponding C question would be quite interesting though.

Comment: Asking "I'm curious about the standard" after acknowledging "VLAs are a compiler extension not present in the standard" is kind of answering your own question. The standard doesn't allow it, because VLAs don't exist in the standard.

Comment: @milleniumbug So, are you saying that above code is invalid for c++?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c++/K_4lgA1JYeg  and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2648.html

Comment: You can't cast to VLAs in C++ because VLAs don't exist in C++.

Comment: @milleniumbug oh ok, wasn't thinking that way. thanks

Comment: @milleniumbug ok, I feel so stupid for using wrong compiler flag. Should have used ´-pedantic´ not ´-ansi´

Comment: Indeed, for maximum conformance, you need to specify `-pedantic` *and* a corresponding standard version, which is `-std=c++03` or `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`